# Customize Swiper.js navigation in Angular

Tags: angular, swiper.js

Is it possible to customize the navigation buttons of swiper.js in angular, as well as locate them outside of the swiper-container? How could I do it?

Answer (score 5):

I found an alternative to be able to handle this, I share it

### .HTML

```
<swiper [config]="config" #customSwiper>
 <div class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let slide of slideData">
  ....
 </div>
</swiper>
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="onBack()" 
class="button-prev">
    <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon>
</button>
<button mat-icon-button color="primary"(click)="onNext()" 
class="button-next">
     <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon>
</button>
```

### .TS

```
import { SwiperComponent } from 'swiper/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  
@ViewChild('customSwiper', { static: false})customSwiper:SwiperComponent;


onBack(){
    this.customSwiper.swiperRef.slidePrev();
}

onNext(){
    this.customSwiper.swiperRef.slideNext();
}

}
```